# R cut function with median as labels rather than bounds

Tags: r, lapply

Is it possible to use the R cut() function with median value as label instead of the cut "bin"?

Here is my current code:

```
> hists <- lapply(data, cut, 100)
> table <- lapply(hists, table)
> head(table$V2)

(0.442,0.892]   (0.892,1.3]    (1.3,1.71]   (1.71,2.12]   (2.12,2.53] 
            1             4             5             7            17
```

What I want is:

```
 > head(table$V2)

0.667   1.096    1.505   1.915   2.325 
   1       4       5       7       17
```

I have tried something like:

```
hists <- lapply(data, cut, 100, labels=(max(x)-min(x))/100)
```

But have no idea how to specify the portion of the data frame that lapply is using (as each of the vectors have different min and max values). Is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempt is not far off.

The key is that inside `lapply` you can define a custom function. Use this feature to create custom labels for every data frame in your list.

You want the median of your quintiles as the labels. You can achieve this by using the `quantile` function in combination with a sequence like `0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9` which are the medians of your quintiles:

```
quants <- seq(0.1, 1, by = 0.2)
hists  <- lapply(data, function(x) cut(x, 5, labels=quantile(x, quants)))
```

Note: If you want 100 breaks instead of 5, just changed quants to `seq(0.005, 1, by = 0.01)` and change the `5` in `cut()` to `100`

PS: never use `data` as a name in `R`, because the name `data` is actually already reserved for other built-in things in `R`. Rather use `df` or so.

Comment: Hey, I actually got around to using this today and I get this message:



``Warning message:
In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  : duplicated levels in factors are deprecated``

I assume that this is because some values will be repeated in the output? Is there a way around this?

Comment: I don't know. I think it may have something to do with the types of variables you have saved in 'data'